# Define char array pointer with size

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, definition

I want a cross between the two declarations below:

```
char string[6];
char * string;
```

I need a pointer with a fixed size and I **don't** want to use `malloc` for something this simple.

All this char array needs to do is be assigned a value and have it retrieved by a function as seen below. (But in a loop hence the separate declaration) What is the best way to do this?

```
string = "words";
printf("%s",string);
```

Comment: What is wrong with a `char *`?  (Well, other than it should be a `const char *`.)

Comment: Is it just good form to use `const char *`? Or is it necessary? Since it's set to "words", it can't be changed, I understand that bit, but why add `const`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have now stated that you can't use @nightcracker's solution, I think you need to use `strncpy()` to assign to the string.

```
char string[6];
/* .... loop code */
strncpy(string, "words", 6);
printf("%s", string);
```

I guess that in a real program you wouldn't be using a string literal, hence the need for `strncpy()`.

Comment: That will do, I was hoping to avoid it but it seems grand.

Answer (score 4):

Define a constant array of which the size gets counted by the initializer:

```
const char string[] = "words";
```

---

If you just want a pointer to a fixed size amount of memory that is small, just use it like this:

```
const int STR_LEN = 10;
char str[STR_LEN];

... loop, etc

strncpy(string, "1234567890", STR_LEN);

... etc
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the assigning and accessing has to be performed in a loop (Hence the prior declaration)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use this:

```
const char * string;
...
string = "words";
printf("%s",string);
```

(or your question is not clear)

Comment: +1: Agreed.  This answers the question as stated.  If it's not appropriate, then the question needs to be clarified.